# What does $T , [$T] , $U stand for in minizinc tutorial

Tags: minizinc

Can someone help me to understand a couple of things in the mini zinc tutorial:

```
function set of $T: 'intersect'(set of $T: x, set of $T: y)
```

This return the intersection of sets x and y . Obviously x and y are sets - but what does $T mean in this context?

```
function var set of int: 'union'(var set of int: x, var set of int: y)
```

Return the union of sets x and y. from what I understand x is a set of integers and y is also a set of integers - but what does  'var set of int' mean? what is 'var' ?

```
function set of $U: array_union(array [$T] of set of $U: x)
```

Return the union of the sets in array x. Could you explain:

```
function set of $U
```

and:

```
array_union(array [$T] of set of $U: x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$T` or `$U` means any type. `$T` can be `int`, `float`, etc. If it says `int`, then you must supply a `int`, but if it says `$T`, you can supply any type.

In the expression `function set of $U: array_union(array [$T] of set of $U: x)`, `$U` and `$T` can be different types but in `function set of $T: 'intersect'(set of $T: x, set of $T: y)` all `$T` have to be the same. Different variables for `$` just means that they can be a different type. Same variable `$` name and all need to have the same type.

Example: `function set of float: array_union(array [int] of set of float: x)` and `function set of int: 'intersect'(set of int: x, set of int: y)`.

`array [$T]` is a bit special and just means that the array can be of any dimension. i.e `array [int]`, `array [int,int]` or `array [int,int,int,int,int]` etc. So `array [$T] of set of $U` means that we have an array of size `$T`, for example `[int,int]`, a two dimensional array. This array is filled with sets of any type. For example sets of integers, for example {1,4,7,145}.

`var int` and `int` are different types. `int` is just regular numbers. `var int` is variable integers, i.e those varaibles that MiniZinc are trying to assign a value to and solve the problem.

For example `var 1..150: age` or
`var int: age` if we want to solve some age problem.

Comment: I get it now. The only thing that I don't get is the : (array [$T]  of set of $U) . is it an array of type $T ? then the.. 'of set of $U' ..  just make me confused. @Kobbe

Comment: maybe you could provide an example of this kind of array and then tell me explicitly what in that array is $T and what is $ U

Comment: Updated the answear with this since it is a bit special.